# Web deploy task failed: data loss might occur

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i am developing ASP.NET application using Entity Framework 6.0, Code-First Strategy. All database operations are isolated to Data Access Layer in separated class library.

Now i want to apply migration which will delete some data in DB. Yes, i understand that this operation will occur some data loss.

When i am trying to publish my ASP.Net project to remote server using MS Web deploy then i recieving following error:

> "The schema update is terminating besause data loss might occur."

So, my question: how to disable data loss checking? I enabled `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;` in EF `Configuration.cs` file. I found some articles that advices to disable option `block incremental deployment if data loss might occur`, but i can not find it in my Visual Studio 2015. It does not exist on Publish tab in project properties.

Comment: Why don't you run the effective migration(s) on the remote db itself?

Comment: When i am using EF Code-First migrations, i am sure that DB will be in actial state in any commit in my git-repository. I would like to keep it =)

Comment: It is 
a work around that I suggest :), until you find a seamless solution.

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem? I am looking for workaround but everywhere the problem is referring to Visual Studio Database project or some SQL tools where is entry like 'block potential data loose' in settings which you can uncheck.